# What is the correct way of importing AngularFireAuth?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I tried this as mentioned in the [official doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md), like the following, which works fine.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth
```

But the VSC tools autosuggest like the following which also works fine.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth/auth
```

Are the above mentioned versions equivalent? If not, what are the differences? What is the best way of importing AngularFireAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code:

- importing from `@angular/fire/auth` would import from [this file](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/public_api.ts) which in TypeScript also called [barrel](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel).
- importing from `@angular/fire/auth/auth` would import from [this file](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts)

Conclusion - the two imports are equivalent since the barrel re-exports the same file.

Regarding the "best way", I always prefer to import from package's public API, since these exports are what actually meant to be consumed by users.